# Error: "The required file tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty es missing"

Tags: external-files

I'm really new at using TeX (my main aim is to convert Markdown to PDF documents). I have successfully installed MiKTeX on my PC, but when I try to make a PDF conversion, I keep getting this message:

> The required file `tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty es missing`

I have Windows on my computer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I suppose you made a basic  install,  and  package `upquote` is not comprised in the basic install. Launch MiKTeX Package Manager (in admin mode if you installed for anyone who uses your computer). The list of available and installed packages will appear within 1-2 min. Select `upquote`, right-click on it, select `install`and wait. That's all.